# Make consumer not to listen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use in Consumer who represent Provider but i want the consumer not to listening, like this:

```
Provider.of<SomeClass>(context, listen: false).DoSomething();
```

can't find any way to do it with Consumer, so i'll be happy to get some help..

Comment: The Consumer is meant to listen and rebuild if anything changes. The code you have mentioned is ideal for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Consumer` is supposed to listen, if you don't want to listen then you would have to use something else, like `Selector` which will only trigger if a condition is met, or even use `Provider.of<SomeClass>(context, listen: false).DoSomething();` directly on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are able to do that by not inserting notifyListeners in ChangeNotifierProvider, for example :

```
class _Provider with ChangeNotifier{ 
   int key=0;

   void changeKey(int newKey){
   key=newKey;

   // No need NotifyListeners();
   }
}
```

and then use consumer as usual